# pandas.DaraFrame resample OHLC based on a non-time value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
    time, price
0   2021-07-23T20:00:00.000221421Z  368.06
1   2021-07-23T20:00:00.001131397Z  368.06
2   2021-07-23T20:00:00.008030544Z  368.06
3   2021-07-23T20:00:00.00807574Z   368.06
4   2021-07-23T20:00:00.008084129Z  368.06
... ... ...
32435   2021-07-23T23:59:46.272261376Z  367.84
32436   2021-07-23T23:59:53.782418944Z  367.84
32437   2021-07-23T23:59:56.24058112Z   367.84
32438   2021-07-23T23:59:58.981374464Z  367.84
32439   2021-07-23T23:59:58.981374464Z  367.84
32440 rows × 2 columns
```

I'm trying to merge the rows into 0.10 OHLC price range intervals, so that the end result looks like this:

```
time, open, high, low, close
0   2021-07-23T20:00:00.000221421Z  368.06  368.06  367.96  367.96
1   2021-07-23T20:00:00.337192Z 367.95  368.04  367.94  368.04
2   2021-07-23T20:00:11.632994Z 368.05  368.06  367.96  368.06
3   2021-07-23T20:00:39.91849344Z   368.07  368.08  367.98  367.98
4   2021-07-23T20:01:04.188584192Z  367.97  368.04  367.94  367.94
```

Here's my attempt, which works but it seems quite slow:

```
import pandas

print('time, open, high, low, close', file = open(file = 'range.csv', mode = 'a'))

dataframe = pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = 'quotes.csv')

bar = [{'time': dataframe.iloc[0, 0], 'open': dataframe.iloc[0, 1], 'high': dataframe.iloc[0, 1], 'low': dataframe.iloc[0, 1], 'close': dataframe.iloc[0, 1]}]

cycle = [0]

while cycle[-1] < len(dataframe.index):
  high = float(bar[-1]['high'])
  low = float(bar[-1]['low'])
  price = float(dataframe.iloc[cycle[-1], 1])
  time = dataframe.iloc[cycle[-1], 0]

  if price < high - 0.10 or price > low + 0.10:
    bar.append({'time': time, 'open': price, 'high': price, 'low': price})
    bar[-2]['close'] = dataframe.iloc[cycle[-2], 1]
    print(bar[-2]['time'], ',', bar[-2]['open'], ',', bar[-2]['high'], ',', bar[-2]['low'], ',', bar[-2]['close'], file = open(file = 'range.csv', mode ='a'))

  if price > high:
    bar[-1]['high'] = price

  if price < low:
    bar[-1]['low'] = price

  cycle.append(cycle[-1] + 1)
```

I'm a novice coder at best, and so my question is this the correct/"pythonic" way of achieving this result, or is there a better way? I haven't found a way of implementing pandas.DataFrame.resample to achieve this result. Thanks in advance for your time!